# AJAX error [object,Object]

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, response, touchatag

this is java code ;

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

      Map<String,Object> hsssmap= new HashMap<String,Object>();
      hsssmap.put("a","true");
      hsssmap.put("b","true");
      write(response,hsssmap);

}
private void write(HttpServletResponse response, Map<String,Object> hsssmap) throws IOException {
         response.setContentType("application/json");       
         response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
         Gson gson = new Gson();
         String json = gson.toJson(hsssmap);
         response.getWriter().write(json);

}
```

Here is js code ;

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $.ajax({
url: 'uri',
    type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: data,

success: function(data){
     $.each (data, function (key,value) {

        alert(key+" "+value);
     });
 },
 error: function (e) {
     alert("error : " + e);
     }

});

return false;
});
```

success event doesnt work. how to fix it ?

Comment: Does your java code gets executed? Have you changed the response type? If you get an error in `$.ajax` method i.e. if the error function gets hit, what's the error message?

Comment: I know nothing about java, but success function doesn't work when server response with not 200 OK

Comment: 'uri' is not a valid resource...you need to specify a valid resource for the url parameter.

Comment: java code is running properly . In final of write function , System.out.println(json)= {"id":"true","password":"true"}

Comment: what do you mean by the success event doesn't work? what does it do? try changing your error function to alert("error:" + e.responseText);

Comment: i changed 'uri' . But nothing change . And 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK . I can send data . But i cant get data.             response.Text={"id":"true","password":true} . im trying to reach this data

Comment: the first parameter is NOT the error message, it's the jqXhr. you should log the second and third parameters, they are statusCode and errorMesage.

Comment: `response.Text` or `responseText`

Comment: statusCode=                                                       error : function ( map ) {

     var code;

     if ( map ) {

      if ( state < 2 ) {

       for ( code in map ) {

        // Lazy-add the new callback in a way that preserves old ones

        statusCode[ code ] = [ statusCode[ code ], map[ code ] ];

       }

      } else {

       // Execute the appropriate callbacks

       jqXHR.always( map[ jqXHR.status ] );

      }

     }

     return this;

    }                             errorMessage : undefined

Comment: HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
response.getWriter().println(id);
session.setAttribute("id",id);
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("View_document.jsp");
view.forward(request, response);

This code was in java code . When i delete this part , properly success . But,i need this session ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the page return some values or not...

try to add alert in success to check it..

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
$.post( "uri", function(data) {
alert( "success" + data.a + data.b );
})
```

if this return you data then your server side servlet working

Comment: assuming the server returns the json header, otherwise this will fail due to strings not having properties.